# Skip certain lines in a big text file using Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, text-files

I have a big text file(several GBs). I want to skip a fixed number of lines, which are repeated in my text file several times. I wrote the following code, which is working as well. I was just wondering if someone could suggest a more efficient way to do this task.

```
coordinate = []
with open('Lammps_D.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    data_iter = iter(data)
    for lines in data_iter:
        if lines[0] == "I":
            next(data_iter)
            next(data_iter)
            next(data_iter)
            next(data_iter)
            next(data_iter)
            next(data_iter)
            next(data_iter)
            next(data_iter)
        else:
            coordinate.append(lines)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading all lines at once and then converting to iterator may be less efficient than just using the file object as iterator using `readline`.

```
coordinate = []
with open('Lammps_D.txt', 'r') as file:
    line=file.readline()
    while line:
      if line[0]=='I':
        for i in range(9): line=file.readline()
      else:
        coordinate.append(line)
        line=file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood you skip lines that are repeated, so all lines that you skip satisfy condition `if lines[0] == "I"`
In that case you could use [itertools.filterfalse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.filterfalse)

```py
from itertools import filterfalse

with open('Lammps_D.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.readlines()
    coordinate = filterfalse(lambda x: x[0] == "I", data)
```

Coordinate is now generator if you want to have it as a list simply just add

```py
coordinate = list(coordinate)
```

Comment: All lines that I skip do not start with "I". When I reach a line starting with "I", I skip that line and also 7 following lines, which they could have a different initial character.